# Secure local interprocess communication toolkit

Tags: windows, open-source, library, c, unix

I am looking for a secure library for interprocess communication between two different, mutually-trusting processes on the same machine.  The library needs to remain secure against attack by programs running as other (unprivileged) users on the same machine.

The library must support both Windows and *nix and expose a C API.  It must be open-source.

Performance is currently not a major concern, but good performance is definitely a plus.